# Optimize "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, optimization, runtime

this is my PostgreSQL code:

```
      Select 'MOBILE' as source, NULL as vtr, NULL as conversions, 
NULL as w, x,y,z from table_1
        where (x,y,z)
            not in        (select x,y,z from table_2)
        UNION
        select 'DESKTOP' as source, vtr, conversions, w,x,y,z
           from table_1;
```

However, this is waaaay too expensive in terms of duration. Is there a "clean" solution for this?
I basically want to exclude all rows in table_1, which also occur in table_2. However, table_2 has 3 more columns (vtr, conversions and w) which is why I do what I'm currently doing. Thanks guys! Found some things here on SOF that didn't really suit my case.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would really help.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  You can say NOT EXIST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with `not exists`:

```
Select 'MOBILE' as source, NULL as vtr, NULL as conversions, NULL as w, x, y, z
from table_1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table_2 t2 where t2.x = t1.x and t2.y = t1.y and t2.z = t1.z)
union all
select 'DESKTOP' as source, vtr, conversions, w, x, y, z
from table_1;
```

For this, you want to be sure you have an index on `table_2(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using join

```
  Select 'MOBILE' as source, NULL as vtr, NULL as conversions, 
NULL as w, x,y,z from table_1 t1 left join table_2 t2
  on t1.x=t2.x and t1.y=t2.y and t1.z=t2.z
where t2.x  is null  and t2.y is null and t2.z is null 
union
select 'DESKTOP' as source, vtr, conversions, w,x,y,z
from table_1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN:

```
Select 'MOBILE' as source, NULL as vtr, NULL as conversions, 
NULL as w, x,y,z from table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_1.x = table_2.x and table_1.y = table_2.y and table_1.z = table_2.z
WHERE table_2.x IS NULL and table_2.y IS NULL and table_2.z IS NULL
UNION
select 'DESKTOP' as source, vtr, conversions, w,x,y,z
from table_1;
```